# Send Location in Facebook messenger api returns with no attachments key/data

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I was using the "location" quick reply explained on this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies to make it easy for someone to send my bot their location.  The message looked like this:

```
    recipient: {
        id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      text: "We can find you with this button",
      quick_replies: [
        {
          content_type:"location",
        }
      ]
    }
```

For some reason (and this only seems to happen for my logged in account as I've had others test and it works properly for them), when the Location feature is used to pick my location, the message received by my bot does not contain the "attachments" attribute that should contain the location details including coordinates.  Even stranger, is that that it WAS working 2 weeks ago.  I've restarted my bot, logged out and back in to FB, and deleted and restarted the conversation, both separately and all at once to start fresh, but nothing seems to help.  I haven't updated any security settings on my account.   The bot is currently not live so I can only have a limited amount of people test to see if anyone else experiences the problem.  I know that it's a shot in the dark, but I'm hoping someone has run into this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug that appears to be affecting a small number of users when they send their location with the quick reply. You can track it here:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/160926314660178